# Understanding a concept in joint probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am taking a course in probability and I am still not getting the fundamental concept on how to express and find the joint probabilities for two or more random variables. Here is a quick setup that i have in mind. Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent discrete random variables that takes values in the non-negative integers. Furthermore, lets assume that they have the same mass function, say $f(k)$. I am really struggling on how to find probabilities such as

> (a) $P(|X_1-X_2| < c)$ for some $c > 0$
>
> (b) $P(X_1 \leq X_2 \leq 2X_1)$

I think that the sets can be written as follows, **which im not sure if there are corrects.**
$$\{|X_1 - X_2| < c\} = \{Y-X<c \} \cap \{X-Y<c\},$$
and that
$$\{X_1 \leq X_2 \leq 2X_1\} = \{X_1 \leq X_2\} \cup \{ X_2 \leq 2X_1\}.$$
But then after this, I don't how to continue working this type of problems. I also know that for instance, that if the sets of possible values of $X_1$ is $A$ and for $X_2$ is $B$, then the joint distribution and mass are given by
$$F(x_1,x_2) = P(X_1 \leq x_1; X_2 \leq x_2), \quad f(x_1,x_2) = P(X_1=x_1;X_2=x_2),$$
and that we can recover the mass function of $X_1$ and $X_2$ by the equations
$$f_{X_1}(x_1) = P(X_1=x, X_2 \in B) = \sum_{x_2 \in B} f(x_1,x_2),$$
$$f_{X_2}(x_2) = P(X_1 \in A, X_2 = x_2) = \sum_{x_1 \in A} f(x_1,x_2).$$
We can even condition the random variables $X_1$ given $X_2 = x_2$ and so on. For instance, if there are independent, I know that we can split the joint distributions and mass functions. Can someone workout those examples carefully to see if I can get the machinery behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your assumptions (discrete, non-negative, independent) the joint distribution is given by
$$
P(X_1=x_1 \cap X_2=x_2)=P(X_1=x_1)\ P(X_2=x_2)=f(x_1)\ f(x_2).
$$
Therefore
$$
P(|X_1-X_2|<c)=\sum_{|x_1-x_2|<c}f(x_1)\ f(x_2),
$$
where the sum is taken for points in an infinite region of the discrete place between the lines $x_1-x_2=c$ and $x_1-x_2=-c$.

Similarly,
$$
P(X_1≤X_2≤2X_1)\sum_{x_1<x_2<2x_1}f(x_1)\ f(x_2)
$$
For another infinite region.